# How to alphabetize a listview item by name and delete it on long press?

Tags: java, android, listview, long-press

I'm trying to figure out how to code something similar to this screenshot:

1. Where I can alphabetize by the title (despite whatever other info is included in that item)?
2. Where i can delete the item when the user long presses on the item for a second or two? (An alert dialog should appear asking the user if he/she wants to delete the item) (In the code, this doesn't work as of yet)

Other Sample code would be much appreciated for both cases. :)

[Screenshot of Movies Not Alphabetized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVENu.png)

Here is the Tab that I want to use to organize movies by title. I just need to figure out how to alphabetize each item by title. For instance, Friends Season 1, Friends Season 2, and ... should be at the end of the list of items.

```
package applications.werst.movie;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment  {

private static final String FILE_NAME = "TitleItemFileName.txt";
private static final String INTERNAL_DIR = "TitleItemDir";
private String TAG = "InternalFileWrite";

ItemListAdapter mAdapter;
public Tab2Fragment () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_current_inventory_view, container, false);

    mAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tab2_LV);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tab2_LL);

    try {
        saveItems();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "FileNotFoundException");
    }


    try {
        loadItems(linearLayout, rootview, container);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
    }

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                       int index, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Open alert dialog here
            showMoreInfo();

            return true;
        }
    });

    return rootview;
}

private void showMoreInfo() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("Do You Want To Delete This Movie/TV Show?");
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_yes_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.moma.org/m"));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_no_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

/** Called when leaving the activity */
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

/** Called when returning to the activity */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

/** Called before the activity is destroyed */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void loadItems(LinearLayout linearlayout, View rootview, ViewGroup container) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = getContext().getApplicationContext().openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        int pos = -1;
        String idnumber = "";
        String title = "";
        String rating = "";
        String runtime = "";
        String genres = "";

        while (null != (idnumber = reader.readLine())) {
            pos++;
            title = reader.readLine();
            rating = reader.readLine();
            runtime = reader.readLine();
            genres = reader.readLine();
            mAdapter.add(new TitleItem(idnumber, title, rating, runtime, genres));

            linearlayout.addView(mAdapter.getView(pos, rootview, container));
        }
}

public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
            deleteRecursive(child);
        }
    }

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}

private void saveItems() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String dir = getContext().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File f0 = new File(dir, FILE_NAME);
    deleteRecursive(f0);

    FileOutputStream fos = getContext().getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            fos)));

    writer.println("1");
    writer.println("Avengers");
    writer.println("PG-13");
    writer.println("125");
    writer.println("Action,Adventure,Animation,Biography,Comedy,Crime,Documentary,Drama,Family,Fantasy,War");
    writer.println("2");
    writer.println("Beethoven");
    writer.println("PG");
    writer.println("96");
    writer.println("Comedy,Western");
    writer.println("3");
    writer.println("Friends: Season 1, Freinds Season 2, Friends Season 3, Friends Season 4, Friends Season 5, Friends Season 6");
    writer.println("TV G");
    writer.println("1500");
    writer.println("Action,Adventure,Animation,Family,Fantasy");
    writer.println("4");
    writer.println("Dodgeball");
    writer.println("PG-13");
    writer.println("111");
    writer.println("Comedy");
    writer.println("5");
    writer.println("Catch Me If You Can");
    writer.println("PG-13");
    writer.println("150");
    writer.println("Action,Comedy");

    writer.close();
}
}
```

Here is the ItemListAdapter that I used to create each item.

```
package applications.werst.movie;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<TitleItem> mItems = new ArrayList<TitleItem>();
private final Context mContext;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

public ItemListAdapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;

}

public void add(TitleItem item) {

    mItems.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void clearitem(int position) {

    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mItems.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {

    return mItems.get(pos);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {

    return pos;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final TitleItem titleItem = (TitleItem) getItem(position);

    RelativeLayout itemLayout = null;
    LayoutInflater relativeLayoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) relativeLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.current_inventory_item, parent, false);

    final TextView TitleView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.TitleView);
    TitleView.setText(titleItem.getTitle());

    final TextView RatingView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.RatingView);
    RatingView.setText(titleItem.getRating());

    final TextView RuntimeView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.RuntimeView);
    RuntimeView.setText(titleItem.getRuntime());

    final TextView GenresView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.GenresView);
    GenresView.setText(titleItem.getGenres());

    return itemLayout;

}
}
```

Comment: Well without code we can't help you very much.  For 1, you would resort the dataset you're using in your adapter, then notifyDataSetChanged.  For 2 you'd remove the item from the data.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm confused by what you mean about "resort the dataset in my adapter and then notifyDataSetChanged?" Sorry, do you mean sort the dataset in my adapter? If so,  how do i go about sorting it? Is there a method/class I can import and use? I'll try to update this post soon with some of my current code

Comment: Code included now. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If the data isn't pulled in dynamically (pagination or something, albeit pagination should account for pulling in data sorted via REST API anyways) sort the collection prior to applying it to the list view adapter?

Comment: How would i go about sorting the collection prior to applying it to the list view adapter?  I have a separate tab that inputs the information to a file,  but that information (i.e. title, genres, runtime, etc) is tacked onto the end of the file.  I was hoping the adapter could somehow sort by the title and i could find that or another movie to delete it on long press. Is there a way to do that?